# Getting jQuery selector to recognize newly-added DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I've searched the jQuery docs and here and can't find an answer to my exact problem...

With a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) spirit, I want to use javascript to add a character object countdown helper to any `textarea` element with `maxlength` and `aria-describedby` attributes.

Obviously I also need to use javascript to monitor `keyup` events to update the counter. I'm using **jQuery 3.6.0**. However, I can't seem to get the countdown method to recognize the newly-added "helper" div element. Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // "characters remaining" countdown
    function textCounter(field) {
        var charLimit = field.attr("maxlength");
        console.log("charLimit=" + charLimit);
        // hack to *double-count* '\r\n' (client/DB discrepency)
        var numLines = (field.val().match(/\n/g) || []).length;
        var charLength = field.val().length + numLines;
        console.log("charLength=" + charLength);
        var charDiff = charLimit - charLength;
        console.log("charDiff=" + charDiff);
        if (charLength > charLimit - numLines)
            field.val(field.val().substring(0, charLimit - numLines));
        var count = $("#" + field.attr("aria-describedby") + " .count");
        console.log(count.html());
        count.html(Math.max(0, charDiff));
    }

    // add countdown helper div
    $("textarea[maxlength]").each(function (e) {
        var helpID = "#" + $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
        var helpDiv = $('<div id="' + helpID + '"><span class="count"></span> characters left.</div>')
        $(this).after(helpDiv);
        textCounter($(this));
    })

    // update counter on keyup events
    $("textarea[maxlength]").keyup(function () { textCounter($(this)); })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="2000" aria-describedby="content-help" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
```

I can confirm that:

1. The helper div element is getting added
2. Via the `console.log` statements, the `textCounter()` method is getting called, but the `count` object resolves to `undefined` (even though it is clearly there), and
3. If the element is hardcoded in HTML (i.e., not dynamically added) the counter works as expected.

Other searches suggest that `.delegate()` or `.on()` are part of the answer, but everything I've tried has the exact same behavior as above. :( Every other Q/A I've come across is, for example, binding a click/hover event to the *newly-added* element, but here it's the `textarea` that needs monitoring (not the new helper element, although it will be updated), if that makes sense...

*Note that I want the solution to work on pages that have multiple textareas, each with potentially different maxlength attributes.*

Any thoughts how to accomplish this?

Comment: The ID of the helper div (helpID) should not include the '#':  https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/yLKVpPm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
var helpID = "#" + $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
```

means that your selector:

```
var count = $("#" + field.attr("aria-describedby") + " .count");
```

Should be:

```
var count = $("#\#" + field.attr("aria-describedby") + " .count");
```

Or you could simply *not* include the `"#"` character when creating the element, giving:

```
var helpID = $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
```

Unfortunately this is a typo question (so it *will* be closed as such), this answer exists only temporarily to clearly show the error.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassingly simple and yes, it fixes everything! :)